# How to use Reactive Cocoa with notifications

Tags: ios, reactive-cocoa

How can I create a signal out of a notification name? For example, I want to go from:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(userDidChange:)
                                             name:kTTCurrentUserLoggedOffNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

to something like:

```
[signalForName(kTTCurrentUserLoggedOffNotification) subscribeNext:^(id x){
...
}];
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`-[NSNotificationCenter rac_addObserverForName:object:]` returns an infinite signal. You can subscribe to it like this

**Objective-c**

```
[[[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] rac_addObserverForName:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil]
  takeUntil:[self rac_willDeallocSignal]]
  subscribeNext:^(id x) {
     NSLog(@"Notification received");
}];
```

**Swift**

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
  .rac_addObserverForName(UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
  .takeUntil(self.rac_willDeallocSignal())
  .subscribeNext { (_) in
     print("Notification received")
  }
```

---

This signal is as stated infinite. If you need this signal/subscription to be bound to the lifetime of `self` you can add `takeUntil:` with `rac_willDeallocSignal` like this:

**Objective-c**

```
[[[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] rac_addObserverForName:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil]
  takeUntil:[self rac_willDeallocSignal]]
  subscribeNext:^(id x) {
     NSLog(@"Notification received");
}];
```

**Swift**

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
  .rac_addObserverForName(UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
  .takeUntil(self.rac_willDeallocSignal())
  .subscribeNext { (_) in
     print("Notification received")
  }
```

Comment: This seems to work, for sure. But if it has to be done like this, then the method is fundamentally flawed. Signals live until there is a reference to them. If the signal is released, then it should be disposed which in turn removes the observer. You may look around in your code, there may be a strong reference to the signal that keeps it from being deallocated. Or if this is not the case, then please report an issue to the project as this is not the expected behavior in my opinion.

Comment: @allprog [Subscribers retain their signals](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/master/Documentation/MemoryManagement.md) until completion, error, or disposal. That's why infinite signals can get pretty gnarly. `-takeUntil:` is a good solution, or something similar that deterministically terminates the signal at a certain point.

Comment: @JustinSpahr-Summers Thanks for the clarification. I knew I was too eager to shout the wolf! But you're there to correct me. :) Could the documentation contain these intricacies? E.g. "this is an infinite signal" and give a pointer to some description that shows what one needs to take into consideration. I'll be honest, the framework seems to have some of these "booby traps" and it would be better if the specifics of the returned signal in these cases were emphasized.

Comment: @allprog That's a fair point. Filed [an issue](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/issues/945) about it.

Answer (score 10):

In the [RACExtensions](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/2.0-development/RACExtensions/NSNotificationCenter+RACSupport.h) you can find the `NSNotificationCenter (RACSupport)` category. That has a method for this purpose:

```
- (RACSignal *)rac_addObserverForName:(NSString *)notificationName
                               object:(id)object;
```

Comment: I experience this is never removed.. Do we need to dispose this signal ourselves?

Comment: The observation is tied to the signal. If that is disposed, then the observer is removed. Can it be that you are keeping strong reference to the signal somewhere? (This is the tricky part of ObjC :) )

Comment: Found out :) see new answer

Answer (score -1):

`Swift` version using `ReactiveCocoa 4.1`:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
      .rac_addObserverForName(UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
      .takeUntil(self.rac_willDeallocSignal())
      .subscribeNext { (_) in
          print("UIKeyboardWillShowNotification")
      }
```